# The total angle must be $ 90 ^{\circ} $ degrees however as we sum up the each angle , the equation be dishold

Tags: angle

[image]

I've drawn the above diagram as same as the diagram of the book.

The leftmost and the right most arrows make $~90^{\circ}~$

Currently I can't get how the below 2 angles are obtained.

$$   \theta_{1}:=  \theta_{} + 45 ^{\circ}  =\text{angle between left M and H}  $$

$$ \theta_{2}:=  \theta_{} - 45 ^{\circ} =\text{angle between right M and H}  $$

$$  \theta_{1} + \theta_{2} = 90 ^{\circ}  $$

must be held but actually

$$  \theta_{1} + \theta_{2} =2 \theta_{} \neq 90  ^{\circ}  $$

I've may made some mistake.

I think we may can assume $~\theta \ll1~$

Comment: The dotted line should be the angle bisector between the two Ms.

Comment: You are mixing up signed and unsigned angles. With the notations on the diagram $\,90^\circ = |\theta+45^\circ|+|\theta-45^\circ|=\theta_1\color{red}{-}\theta_2\,$.

Comment: What are signed ,unsigned angles?

Comment: @mechatronicsenthusiast $\,\theta_2=\theta-45^\circ \lt 0\,$ If you are supposed to use signed (a.k.a. oriented) angles, then that was probably defined/described somewhere in the textbook prior to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The above circled part shows your error. It should be $45-\theta$ and not the other way round.

Now continue and you get $\theta+45$ and $45-\theta$. Now can you complete the answer yourself?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

$\theta_1 + \theta_2 = 2\times\theta $ and definitely does not equal $90$.

The sum is not supposed to be equal to $90$ as $2\times\theta$ is not equal to $90$.

On the other hand: $\theta_1 - \theta_2 = 90$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Good work Nassim

Answer (score 0):

Angle between M and H is ($45-\theta$) not ($\theta-45$). Angle between M and H  ,left one,is ($45+\theta$) or ($\theta+45$). So the sum of two angles is:

$\theta+45+45-\theta=90$